# Transform a function with a homothecy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What expression describes how a function $y(x)$ is transformed under a general homothetic transformation?

I'd like to prove that if I apply a homothetic transformation to a particular solution I obtain a new such solution.

Comment: What does it mean to transform a function under a general homothetic transformation?

Comment: If under a reflexion over the $y$-axis the function transforms as $y(x) \to y(-x)$, is there a similar equation for a homothetic transformation?

Comment: If you want a homothety with respect to the origin and factor $r$, the $f(x)$ should turn into $rf(x/r)$. This is because a homothety is equivalent to scaling in the horizontal direction followed by the same scaling in the vertical direction. If you want it to have center at some other point then you have to translate to that point first, do the transformation and translate back. Suppose you wan the center to be at $(a,b)$. Translating $f$ gives $f(x+a)-b$. Then apply the transformation from before $rf(x/r+a)-rb$. Finally translate back $rf((x-a)/r+a)-rb+b$.

Comment: @SergioGonzález Do you want an expression for $y(h(x))$, where $h$ is a homothecy? Or do you want to know the expression for the function whose graph is the graph of $y$ after applying a homothecy?